# No consigo hacer funcionar Mustache

Tags: javascript, template

Estoy siguiendo un tutorial sobre java script modular, en el mismo intento crear en mi servidor una pequeña prueba como en el siguiente codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGoKYN?editors=101
No he usado nunca Mustache pero parece ser interesante aunque no consigo hacer que funcione ni se vea como en el codepen, ¿alguna idea?

index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/2.1.2/mustache.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>


<div id="peopleModule">
    <h1>People</h1>
    <input placeholder="name" type="text">
    <button id="addPerson">Add Person</button>
    <ul id="people">
        <script id="people-template" type="text/template">
            {{#people}}
                <li>
                    <span>{{.}}</span>
                    <i class="del">X</i>
                </li>
            {{/people}}
        </script>
    </ul>
</div>
```

script.js

```
var people = (function(){
    var people = ['Will', 'Steve'];

    // cache DOM
    var $el = $('#peopleModule');
    var $button = $el.find('button');
    var $input = $el.find('input');
    var $ul = $el.find('ul');
    var template = $el.find('#people-template').html();

    // bind events
    $button.on('click', addPerson);
    $ul.delegate('i.del', 'click', deletePerson);

    render();

    // functions
    function render(){
        Mustache.parse(template);
        var rendered = Mustache.render(template, {people: people});
        $ul.html(rendered);
    }

    function addPerson(value){
        var name = (typeof value === "string") ? value : $input.val();
        people.push(name);
        render();
        $input.val('');
        console.log(people);
    }

    function deletePerson(event){
        var $remove = $(event.target).closest('li');
        var i = $ul.find('li').index($remove);

        people.splice(i, 1);
        render();
    }

    function returnPeople(){
        console.log(people);
    }

    return{
        addPerson: addPerson,
        deletePerson: deletePerson,
        returnPeople: returnPeople
    }


})();
```

Comment: Si en la consola llamo a las funciones funciona:
people.addPerson("Pepe") y devuelvo el array con 
people.returnPeople() -> 1Array [ "Will", "Steve", "Pepe" ] aunque me sale tambien un undefined al hacer el addPerson que viene del render(). Es como que no está cogiendo la plantilla el mustache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> El error seguramente es por la ubicación del `script.js`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Ten en cuenta que el contenido de este se encuentra en un [`IIFE`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) y **se esta ejecutando antes de que se cargue el `HTML` que esta por debajo**.

> Una solución podría ser mover el `script` al final del documento.

Por ejemplo:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/2.1.2/mustache.min.js"></script>

<div id="peopleModule">
    <h1>People</h1>
    <input placeholder="name" type="text">
    <button id="addPerson">Add Person</button>
    <ul id="people">
        <script id="people-template" type="text/template">
            {{#people}}
                <li>
                    <span>{{.}}</span>
                    <i class="del">X</i>
                </li>
            {{/people}}
        </script>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- Justo debajo del html a ser afectado -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: cierto! error de novato, intenté colocarlo dentro del document.ready y con uno funciona pero a la hora de conectar 2 módulos no se conectan entre sí, dde esta forma funciona perfectamente.